# Admob rewarded video Ad Failed to load TEST

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, some time ago I started to try the Rewarded test ads with Admob, everything went well! Now that I wanted to try test ads again, they do not show up, I even create a new project and implement only the Rewarded and it does not work, but if I place an Interstitial if it works.

*I have read innumerable publications, but all are based on the user ID Admob itself but not in the test.*

> Always: **onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad**

This is the code with the new project I made:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
                reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Reward the user.
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I also added:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

And...

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

Logcat:

```
Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.DummyAdapter
    android.os.RemoteException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbo(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbm(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzago.zzca(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzahx.zzdn(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajy.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-08 02:07:01.761 4917-4917/android.cinemovil.videos W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

*It is worth mentioning that internet permits are established in the manifest.*

I clarify that I'm only using the Android Studio emulator. A couple of weeks ago I did everything the same and I got the test rewards videos without problem.

I have in my Interstitial app and show without problems, only Rewarded is that it does not seem to work.

Also try placing my Rewarded user ID and it still does not work. (My account already shows Interstitial and banner)

Comment: Resolved your question? i am also face same problem.

Comment: @Javacoder Yes! I was using an emulator that did not have Google Play services, and when I was testing directly from my cell phone, I had blocked the ads directly from the HOSTS (Root) file, so it did not work and I did not know it.